# AsyncTask when is onCancelled() is called besides calling AsyncTask.cancel?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Currently I have a View which has a AsyncTask class used for decoding.
But eventhough AsyncTask.cancel() is not called within my class, onCancelled() has been called which resulted to some abnormal process in my application.

I would like to ask if what are any instances that AsyncTask.onCancelled() will be called
besides when calling the AsyncTask.cancel()

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Same question - I get logs like this:

    onPreExecute()
    onCancelled()
    doInBackground()
    onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

I think that calling the Cancel method will trigger the onCancelled event (?), in where you can write some code to cancel your task gracefully.

Comment: Yes when calling cancel() will call onCancelled() but what I would like to know is that is there any other instances that onCancelled will be called i.e. when the application crashed etc.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? It clearly says when onCancelled is invoked: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled()

Comment: @Frederick - With breakpoints on all `.cancel(true)` calls, onCancelled() is still run after `onPreExecute()` but before `doInBackground()`. Documentation doesn't help in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hrm...

Posting `.cancel()` before the AsyncTask is executed means a cancel actually happens during the execution... which is obviously incorrect behaviour.

Found this our by placing all calls to `.cancel(true)` in my code into a single method called "cancel()" which I could then set a debug on and step out of to find the offending piece of code.